# Getting `unreachable code` when trying to close resources

Tags: java

I am trying to close the `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` but I am getting an `unreachable code` error which doesn't even allow me to run, here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultipleClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

            Socket socket = new Socket(ip, 4571);

            DataInputStream inputFromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outputToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            while (true) {

                System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF());
                int choice = scan.nextInt();

                if (choice == 1) {
                    outputToServer.writeInt(choice);
                    System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF());
                    }
                }

            }
            scan.close();
            inputFromServer.close();
            outputToServer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I am getting that because Eclipse is detecting that this lines precede a `while(true)` which might be confusing however, I have had a similar code working fine, I tried comparing between both and I can't see the difference, here is the other code:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
  
public class MultipleClient { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        try { 
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
              
            // Getting local IP Address (127.0.0.1)
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost"); 
      
            // Establish the connection with Server on port 5056
            Socket socket = new Socket(ip, 5056); 
            // This will trigger the accept() function of the Server
      
            // Receiving input and sending output to Server
            DataInputStream inputFromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); 
            DataOutputStream outputToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 

            while (true) { 
                System.out.println(inputFromServer.readUTF()); 
                String tosend = scan.nextLine(); 
                outputToServer.writeUTF(tosend); 
                  
                // Sending Exit closes the connection and breaks the loop
                if(tosend.equals("Exit")) 
                { 
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Closing this connection : " + socket); 
                    socket.close(); 
                    System.out.println("Connection closed"); 
                    break; 
                } 
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                // Printing message received from Server 
                String received = inputFromServer.readUTF(); 
                System.out.println(received); 
            } 
              
            // Closing resources 
            scan.close(); 
            inputFromServer.close(); 
            outputToServer.close(); 
        }catch(Exception e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: It is not Eclipse detecting the unreachable code, but the java compiler. The "similar code" has a branch within the loop, that contains a `break;`. The code reporting the unreachable code does not have a `break;` within the `while (true)`-loop.

Comment: As an aside, you should put your close calls in a finally block for your try so that your streams are guaranteed to be closed even in the case of an exception.

Comment: thank you both, as a bit of a side question, could this be related to getting a broken pipe error? I posted about it on here earlier today  and I thought maybe closing the resources would fix it but it didn't so is it about having the finally block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply have a `while(true) {...}` block that doesn't even have a break statement so yeah those statements after it are unreachable ...

You have two choices:

1. Introduce a local variable initialized with `true` which will be updated inside the loop
2. Create a break statement like the second part of your uploaded code that will stop the loop when it meets a certain condition